# Error en condicional

Tags: java

Hola necesito crear una cola utilizando vectores en Java y no comprendo por qué la condición no funciona cuando mi vector esta lleno.

```
import java.util.Vector;

public class ColaVector {
    private Vector<Integer> cola = new Vector<Integer> (3);
    public int elementosEncolados = 0;



    public void insertarAlFinal(int elemento) {

        if (this.elementosEncolados <= this.cola.size()) {

        this.cola.add(elemento);
        this.elementosEncolados++;

        } else {
            System.out.println("No se puede insertar. Cola llena");
    }

    public int primerValor() { 
       return cola.firstElement();
    }

}
```

Aquí está la clase main desde donde llamo a todas las clases mostradas en el cuadro anterior y como se puede ver mi vector de 4 elementos esta lleno y al imprimir por pantalla el primer valor debería mostrar también que está lleno.

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ColaVector c1 = new ColaVector();


    c1.insertarAlFinal(1);
    c1.insertarAlFinal(2);
    c1.insertarAlFinal(3);
    c1.insertarAlFinal(4);
    c1.insertarAlFinal(5);
    c1.insertarAlFinal(6);
    c1.insertarAlFinal(7);


    System.out.println( c1.primerValor() );


    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

La condicion si se aplica pero usted piensa que hace una cosa, cuando hace otra:

```
public void insertarAlFinal(int elemento) {

        System.out.println("" + this.elementosEncolados);
        System.out.println("" + this.cola.size());

        if (this.elementosEncolados <= this.cola.size()) {

        this.cola.add(elemento);
        this.elementosEncolados++;

        }
```

Lo anterior tendria una salida mas o menos asi:

```
0
0
1
1
2
2
3
3
```

Puede ver que tanto elementos como size crecen al mismo tiempo, ahora sin hacer muchos cambios y viendo como inicializa el vector usted podria usar lo siguiente:

```
public void insertarAlFinal(int elemento) {     

        if (this.elementosEncolados + 1 < this.cola.capacity()) {

        this.cola.add(elemento);
        this.elementosEncolados++;

        } else {
            System.out.println("No se puede insertar. Cola llena");
    }
    }
```

Cambiamos `this.cola.size()` por `this.cola.capacity()` y `<=` por `this.elementosEncolados + 1 <` aunque esto ultimo es solo para que su codigo
pueda hacer lo que busca usted lo puede cambiar y ajustar mejor. pues pienso que su principal error era que quizas estaba confundido con `size()` y `capacity()`

Lo anterior tendria una salida asi:

```
0
3
1
3
2
3
No se puede insertar. Cola llena
```

Por cierto le falta un `}` en el metodo `insertarAlFinal`

- [`size()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#size()) devuelve el numero de componentes el el vector en este caso.
- [`capacity()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#capacity()) devuelve la capacidad actual del vector.

[`Vector class`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html)

Answer (score 1):

Primeramente, debes usar capacity() para obtener tu capacidad inicial en tu vector, luego hacer algunas adecuaciones para que tu if valide correctamente los 3 elementos que deben entrar en la cola :

Nota: La clase Vector se indica una capacidad inicial y como segundo argumento el tamaño que irá incrementando:

Cuando creamos un vector u objeto de la clase Vector, podemos especificar su dimensión inicial, y cuanto crecerá si rebasamos dicha dimensión.

> ```
> Vector vector=new Vector(20, 5);
> ```

```
package com.stack.over.flow.ejemplos;

import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.Vector;

public class ColaVector {

    private Vector<Integer> cola = new Vector<Integer>(3);
    public int elementosEncolados = 0;
    static int capacidadCola = 0;

    public void insertarAlFinal(int elemento) {
        try {

            if (this.elementosEncolados < capacidadCola) {

                this.cola.add(elemento);
                this.elementosEncolados++;

            } else {
                System.out.println("No se puede insertar. Cola llena");
            }
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (Exception e2) {
            e2.printStackTrace();

        }

    }

    public int primerValor() {
        return cola.firstElement();
    }

    public static void getCapacidadInit() {
        ColaVector obj = new ColaVector();
        capacidadCola = obj.cola.capacity();
        System.out.println("capacidad es : " + capacidadCola);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        getCapacidadInit();
        ColaVector c1 = new ColaVector();

        c1.insertarAlFinal(1);
        c1.insertarAlFinal(2);
        c1.insertarAlFinal(3);
        c1.insertarAlFinal(4);
        c1.insertarAlFinal(5);
        c1.insertarAlFinal(6);
        c1.insertarAlFinal(7);

        System.out.println(c1.primerValor());

    }

}
```